# Why at the end all the fruits of the efforts are offered to Krishna and not Rama etc?

Tags: krishna, rituals

Usually at the end of the any rituals it is said as `sarvam sree krishnaarpanam` (all the outcomes belongs to Krishna - a crude translation) and Krishna name is chanted thrice or ten times.

Vaishnavites use a prayer called [saathivk thyagam](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/bhakti/archives/jun2000/0075.html) (sacrifice of all outcome of the efforts) in which it is said to offered to Baghavan and none in specific.

Why is that it is dedicated to Krishna and why not Rama etc. I mean is there any specific reason behind it?

Comment: Consider like this: the name of the Supreme Soul is more famous as `Krsna`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. We say śrī Kṛṣṇārpaṇamastu (श्री कृष्णार्पणमस्तु) at the end of almost every ritual. It means everything goes to śrī Kṛṣṇā.

Not only people whose ishta devata is Krishna say this but almost every Hindu says this.

**Why only Krishna not Rama etc., ?**

In the Bhagavad Gita, Krishna Paramatma says to Arjuna :

> यत्-करोषि यद्-अश्नासि यज्-जुहोषि ददासि यत् |
>   यत्-तपस्यसि कौन्तेय तत्-कुरुष्व मद्-अर्पणम् || २७ ||
>
> yat-karoṣi yad-aśnāsi yaj-juhoṣi dadāsi yat |
>   yat-tapasyasi kaunteya tat-kuruṣva mad-arpaṇam || 9.27 ||
>
> Whatever you do, whatever you eat, whatever you offer in sacrifice, whatever you give away, whatever austerity you practice, O Kaunteya, do that as an offering to Me.

By this verse he assures that He will take the offering to the proper destination without any cuts and discounts. People who worship other deities(Shiva, Amba, etc.,) too say śrī Kṛṣṇārpaṇamastu for this reason.

**Commentary of Bhagavad Ramanujacharya on above verse :**

Whatsoever secular work you do for the maintenance of the body, whatsoever you set aside for the sustenance of the body, whatsoever religious rites, obligatory (nityam) and occasional (naimittikam) you practice, like offering oblations into the sacred fire, performing charity and austerity — do all these as an offering to Me. Arpaṇa means offering — do all acts, secular and religious, as if the doer, the enjoyer and the worshipped were all offerings to Me.

---

There are other verses too

> कायेन वाचा मनसेन्द्रियैर्वा
>   बुद्ध्यात्मना वा प्रकृतेः स्वभावात् ।
>   करोमि यद्यत्सकलं परस्मै
>   नारायणायेति समर्पयामि ॥
>
> kāyena vācā manasendriyairvā
>   buddhyātmanā vā prakṛteḥ svabhāvāt ।
>   karomi yadyatsakalaṃ parasmai
>   nārāyaṇāyeti samarpayāmi ॥
>
> (Whatever I do) with my Body, Speech, Mind or Sense Organs,: (Whatever I do) using my Intellect, Feelings of Heart or (unconsciously) through the natural tendencies of my Mind, Whatever I do, I do all for others (i.e. without the sense of attachment to the results), (And) I Surrender them all at the Lotus Feet of Sreemannarayana.

If your destination is moksha, you should not possess any fruits of efforts you have done. puṇya takes you Swarga and pāpā takes you to hell. These too are are not considered moksha. SO if you want to gain the moksha the liberation, all your fruits of effort should be given to the supreme Lord.

That's the reason we offer our deeds saying śrī Kṛṣṇārpaṇamastu (श्री कृष्णार्पणमस्तु) or similar statement.

Comment: Why on earth everyone will offer his worship to Krishna when he is worshiping some other deity?Every deity has a specific arapna mantra..most generally used is " tat sat brahmarpanamstu'..others are Devi arpanamastu,Shivarpanamstu,Durgarpanamastu..etc..For ex- in [this](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_deities_misc/chandrashekharendrapUjAvidhAnam.html?lang=en-IN) puja  Jagadguru Chandrasekhara sarasawti uses- **etatphalaM sarvaM shrIparameshvarArpaNamastu**..Specially if one is worshipping Sri Lalita or Bhagavati Chandi offering worship to some other deity is a big blunder to do..

Comment: @RIckross It is because Krishna said he is the supreme soul. Yes. It depends on ishta devata. The above verse can also interpreted as "Give that offering to me. I will make sure that it reaches the destination without any fail." But many say Krishnarpanamastu. You can also refer other comentaries too.

Comment: That must only be a vaishnava thing..otherwise which fool will offer worship to Krishna or for that matter to any other deity after worshiping Sri Lalita for example..That is not short of a grave crime..and Btw what was the method before Bhagavat Gita was composed?

Comment: No. Don't say fool. Be polite. It would be Sreemannarayanarpanamastu. Krishna is Narayana himself.  But if you are doing so. It is your wish.  He will take the offering to the proper destination without any cuts and discounts. But all the fruits will be given to the supreme lord only. In BG, he says he is the supreme. Refer 9 adhyaya.

Comment: Sree Charan There is nothing in what i have said that is harsh..I never said that the devotees of a particular Deity is a fool..I simply said if someone worshiping Sri Lalita Devi and at the end offers worship to some other Deity then that's nothing short of a crime..And as far as supremacy is considered,pls keep Sri Lalita out the that..because her supremacy is unquestinable..can't be denied by any means..Lalita created Vedas from her breath,Vigneswara from her smile,Rudra,Vishnu from her eyes and the KrishnAdi 10 Vishnu avatars from her finger nails..(Refer to Brahmanda Puran)..

Comment: and in Devi Bhagavatam Mahavishnu finds himself in a fingertoe nail of Devi who was then in her Virata Rupa..Devi Lalita is also constatly served by Goddess Saraswati and Laksmi(consort of Narayana)..

Comment: @Rickross you are right. I had read in some spiritual site that he who worships a deity and offers the worship to another deity, then he gets no fruits instead he is cursed by both the deities. And as for everyone saying "**Krishna said in BG, this chapter, this verse... I am supreme and all worship goes to me**" then in each Puraana each deity has said that all worship goes to Me. Just because BG is known more does not add to it being the ONLY scripture ever written. For Vaishnavas it goes to Vishnu, Shaivas it goes to Shiva, Shaaktas it goes to Devi , for Advaitins it goes to Para Brahma.

Comment: That is there in Tantras.. that verse is in Kularnava @AnuragSingh

Comment: @AnuragSingh Even when you say the wrong name, it goes to the same God. It is not like the if bhakta is shakta, it will go to Shakti, bhakta is Shaiva, it goes to Shiva. There is and will be only one supreme. He doesn't change if someone sees him as different. Truth is truth. If you want to talk whether his comment is right or wrong, talk to him in chat room. If you want to ask any clarifications, comment on my answer. Comments are not for chatting with a person who has already commented. .

Answer (score 3):

Krishna and rama are same but krishna is called purnavatar(full incarnation).
Every thing and every partical of this universe is Krishna. Krishna is inside us we are within Krishna.
One interesting thing you should know that Rama and krishna were exactly copy of each other except their eyes.
राम कृष्णा दोउ एक हैं, अंतर नहीं निमेष।
इनके नयन गंभीर हैं, उनके चपल विशेष।

Comment: Thanks Deepak, as far as I have learnt, both avatars are considered as purna avatar.  There are other avatars like Sri Nrismha, Sri Govinda (Balaji) etc. They are not being offered.

Comment: @Narayanan - There are people who do Rama arpanam, Shiva arpanam etc. One reason that Krishna arpanam is common because Krishna moved with everyone from animals, simpletons like gokula people and also with mighty, old etc. Rama also moved with people, but he was King, emperor even when he was in exile. He had select people like Guha, sabari, Sugriva, Hanuman etc but Rama's mingling with common downtown people was less compared to Krishna. This is what i heard from a srivaishnava scholar.

Comment: @Krishna Which people say Ramarpanam or Shivarpanam?

Comment: @Keshav - what i mean is there are people who based on their ista devatha do say Raama arpanam, Siva arpanam, albeit their numbers may be small...Also, Sri Vaishnavas say Govinda arpanam also, which is queit famous..

Comment: Could you translate the last sentence of your answer that is in hindi? Thanks