# Mantra to say at the end of work?

Tags: mantras

At the beginning of work we say ॐ श्री गणेशाय नमः ||  , pray to Lord Ganesha to remove obstacles etc.

Is there any mantra to be said at end of puja or work, praying that the work may give good results?

Comment: krishnarpnamasthu  in short if you do vishnushasranama parayan then kayena vasha manshyeindriyerva budhiyath manava prekuthes swbhavath karomi eth eth sakalam parasmai narayanaathei samarpayami by any chances if you are hanuman baktha best is do barathi ramana mukhya parana anthargatha krsihnarpnamasthu and give water oblatlatoin

Comment: I read to use (Gods Name)(Obligation word) Obligation word being:समर्पयामि / प्रीत्यर्थे / प्रित्यर्थम् / र्पणमस्तु..
I dont know Sanskrit much..So How Do I decide which obligation word to use..which is commanly used..
Is there any gender based usage..?

Comment: i said by uttering above said mantra you just give arghya with water that is what is ment by oblation

Comment: I understood that..but what if the puja is for different God..in that case I thought its (Gods Name)(Obligation word)..?..Which Obligation word is commanly used..Is there any gender based usage..?

Comment: all in sum total you should give it phala or result to krishna only as stated in bhagavad gita by krishna himself.. if you change that its upto you..

Comment: I got that doubt by reading this [Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8109/why-at-the-end-all-the-fruits-of-the-efforts-are-offered-to-krishna-and-not-rama).. ans this [Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13811/19305)

Comment: Among Obligation word being:समर्पयामि / प्रीत्यर्थे / प्रित्यर्थम् / र्पणमस्तु.. I dont know Sanskrit much..So How Do I decide which obligation word to use..which is commanly used.. Is there any gender based usage..?

Comment: @PrasannaR ^^^^

Comment: Saying thanks would be sufficient I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103386/discussion-between-prasanna-r-and-hindukid).

Comment: Om Shanti......